# Axon query maximum size returning

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have an Axon Query that collects List of Objects from a repository.

I worry about a case when I have too big data returning.
Is there some restrictions on it? And how to handle extra data ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is knowing maximum gRPC message size, which is 4,2 mB

To increase maximum gRPC message size: AxonServer configuration axon.axonserver.max-message-size in the client configuration

And maximum query timeout is 5 minutes You can increase this timeout by setting the property axoniq.axonserver.default-command-timeout. The value of the property is the timeout in milliseconds.